# how to convert URI into Bip21

Tags: bitcoinj, java, bip21-uri

i am trying to convert the

> URI into BIP21

currently i am generating **URI from bitcoinj** library, but i want it to be on **BIP21** Standard. i have read many articles but didn't found any solution

Comment: Do you have an example of an URI generated by bitcoinj lib?

Comment: yes here: "mqe8V3Vrp77JKYG2tfnQ6P8wpN4YVZ84V2"

Comment: Have you tried convertToBitcoinURI(String address, Coin amount, String label, String message) or convertToBitcoinURI(Address address, Coin amount, String label, String message) ? or https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bip21

Comment: no i didn't try this...

Comment: yes i try this but didn't work for me

Comment: Did you get an error or something else?

Comment: well, i couldn't access the convertToBitcoinURI

Comment: This is how i am generating URI                                                                     
        // Derive address
        mAddress = mECKey.toAddress(mParams);

Comment: Ohh I forgot, you have access the method in BitcoinURI , so like that ......................................................            String bitcoinURI = BitcoinURI.convertToBitcoinURI(String address, Coin amount, String label, String message)

Comment: did this generate BIP21 URI for me?

Comment: bitcoin:mqe8V3Vrp77YMZG2tfnQ6P8wpN4YVZ84V2?amount=0.000001&label=bla&message=So%20this%20is%20it%21%20hmm...This is i got when i print

Comment: That is bip21...???

Comment: Seems fine to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [source file for that method is here](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/uri/BitcoinURI.java)

[BIP21 wiki](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0021.mediawiki)

Method can be accessed like this

```
 String bitcoinURI = BitcoinURI.convertToBitcoinURI(String address, Coin amount, String label, String message);
```